# dialog getlocationonscreen

Tags: android, dialog, keyboard

I have a dialog with an EditText, and when the user clicks on it, the soft keyboard appears and pushes the dialog up. When the keyboard is dismissed, the EditText resumes its original position. This is standard behavior. The EditText has clearly moved, but calling `getLocationOnScreen()`, return the same result for both positions,under rom 4.0.x or below;  for example ,dialog was set at 100,1100 with device 720*1280, when keyboard shown, at 4.0.x get both (100,1100), but on 4.1 device get (100,1100),(100,679)

anyone knows what parameters modified while the softkeyboard was shown with foucs of dialog's editText;
i'd done this.

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```